# Gauss Quadrature to approximate Bezier Curve length in Java

Tags: java, math, bezier

I am trying to figure out how to approximate the length of my nth degree Bezier curve and I found out that I could use the Gauss Quadrature integration to approximate it. After multiple attempts with my control points of P1(220, 40), P2(220, 260) P3(35, 200) and P4(120, 160) my program should give me a curve length of 272.87 (as seen from the graph [here](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#arclength)); however, I have only been getting results of around 229.18. I have checked my constants from the [GaussLegendre class](https://github.com/AlessandroGnoatto/matrix-functions/blob/master/matrix-functions/src/com/alessandrognoatto/basics/GaussLegendre.java) and they are correct.
Could somebody please tell me what I did wrong.

This is the class in full

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import org.waltonrobotics.controller.PathData;
import org.waltonrobotics.controller.Pose;

/**
 * Everything about Bezier Curves https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/
 */
public class DynamicBezierCurve extends Path {

    private final double startVelocity;
    private final double endVelocity;
    private final int degree;
    private double[] coefficients;

    /**
     * This constructor is used with the splines, but feel free to use it when creating your own motions
     *
     * @param vCruise - the cruise velocity of the robot
     * @param aMax - the maximum acceleration of the robot
     * @param startVelocity - the start velocity
     * @param endVelocity - the end velocity
     * @param isBackwards - whether or not to move the robot backwards
     * @param controlPoints - the control points that define the curve
     */
    public DynamicBezierCurve(double vCruise, double aMax, double startVelocity, double endVelocity,
        boolean isBackwards, List<Pose> controlPoints) {
        super(vCruise, aMax, isBackwards, controlPoints);
        this.startVelocity = startVelocity;
        this.endVelocity = endVelocity;
        // The starting average encoder distance should always be 0

        degree = getKeyPoints().size() - 1;
        coefficients = calculateCoefficients(degree);
    }

    public DynamicBezierCurve(double vCruise, double aMax, double startVelocity, double endVelocity,
        boolean isBackwards,
        Pose... controlPoints) {
        this(vCruise, aMax, startVelocity, endVelocity, isBackwards, Arrays.asList(controlPoints));
    }

    /**
     * Uses the formula to find the value of nCr
     *
     * @return nCr
     */
    private static double findNumberOfCombination(int n, int r) {
        int nFactorial = factorial(n);
        int rFactorial = factorial(r);
        int nMinusRFactorial = factorial(n - r);

        return nFactorial / (rFactorial * nMinusRFactorial);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the factorial of any integer or double, d
     *
     * @return the factorial of d
     */
    private static int factorial(int d) {
        int result = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i <= d; i++) {
            result = result * i;
        }

        return result;
    }


    public double computeArcLength() {

        int n = 10;

        GaussLegendre gl = new GaussLegendre(n, -1, 1);

        double[] t = gl.getNodes();
        double[] C = gl.getWeights();
        double z = 1;

        double sum = 0;

        double zDivision = z / 2;

        for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
            double ti = t[i];
            ti = zDivision * ti + zDivision;

            Pose point = getDerivative(ti);

            double Ci = C[i];

            sum += Ci * Math.hypot(point.getX(), point.getY());
        }

        sum = zDivision * sum;

        return sum;
    }

    @Override
    public PathData createPathData(double startAverageEncoderLength, PathData previousPathData, double percentage) {
        Pose centerPoint = getPoint(percentage);

        PathData pathData;
//      pathData= calculateData(startAverageEncoderLength, previousPathData, centerPoint);
        pathData = new PathData(centerPoint);
        return pathData;
    }


    private Pose getDerivative(double percentage) {
        double dx = 0;
        double dy = 0;

        if (percentage == 1.0) {

            int last = getKeyPoints().size() - 1;

            dx = getKeyPoints().get(last).getX()
                - getKeyPoints().get(last - 1).getX();
            dy = getKeyPoints().get(last).getY()
                - getKeyPoints().get(last - 1).getY();
        } else {

            for (int i = 0; i < degree; i++) {

                Pose pointI = getKeyPoints().get(i);

                double multiplier =
                    coefficients[i] * StrictMath.pow(1 - percentage, (degree - i)) * StrictMath
                        .pow(percentage, (double) i);

                Pose nextPointI = getKeyPoints().get(i + 1);

                dx += (multiplier = multiplier * (degree)) * (nextPointI.getX() - pointI.getX());
                dy += multiplier * (nextPointI.getY() - pointI.getY());
            }
        }

        double angle = StrictMath.atan2(dy, dx);

        if (isBackwards()) {
            angle += Math.PI;
        }
        angle %= (2 * Math.PI);

        return new Pose(dx, dy, angle);
    }

    private Pose getPoint(double percentage) {
        return getPoint(degree, percentage);
    }

    /**
     * @param percentage - t
     * @return the Pose that is at percentage t along the curve
     */
    private Pose getPoint(double degree, double percentage) {
        double xCoordinateAtPercentage = 0;
        double yCoordinateAtPercentage = 0;

        double dx = 0;
        double dy = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= degree; i++) {

            Pose pointI = getKeyPoints().get(i);

            double multiplier =
                coefficients[i] * StrictMath.pow(1 - percentage, (degree - i)) * StrictMath.pow(percentage, (double) i);

            xCoordinateAtPercentage += (multiplier * pointI.getX());
            yCoordinateAtPercentage += (multiplier * pointI.getY());

            if (percentage != 1 && i < degree) {
                Pose nextPointI = getKeyPoints().get(i + 1);

                dx += (multiplier = multiplier * (degree)) * (nextPointI.getX() - pointI.getX());
                dy += multiplier * (nextPointI.getY() - pointI.getY());
            }
        }

        if (percentage == 1.0) {
            int last = getKeyPoints().size() - 1;

            dx = getKeyPoints().get(last).getX()
                - getKeyPoints().get(last - 1).getX();
            dy = getKeyPoints().get(last).getY()
                - getKeyPoints().get(last - 1).getY();
        }

        double angle = StrictMath.atan2(dy, dx);

        if (isBackwards()) {
            angle += Math.PI;
        }
        angle %= (2 * Math.PI);

        return new Pose(xCoordinateAtPercentage, yCoordinateAtPercentage, angle);
//      return new Pose(dx, dy, angle);
    }


    /**
     * Updates the coefficients used for calculations
     */
    private double[] calculateCoefficients(int degree) {
        double[] coefficients = new double[degree + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < coefficients.length; i++) {
            coefficients[i] = findNumberOfCombination(degree, i);
        }

        return coefficients;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the source of GaussLegendre?

Comment: what happens when you increase n to  99?

Comment: @RyanTheLeach here is the source code for the GaussLegendre class https://github.com/AlessandroGnoatto/matrix-functions/blob/master/matrix-functions/src/com/alessandrognoatto/basics/GaussLegendre.java

Comment: @AngelKoh changing the n seems to not change anything it always returns the same number

Comment: Bezier curves are piecewise polynomials, is that right? If so then it seems you should be able to work out the arc length symbolically, perhaps with some assistance from a symbolic computation system such as Maxima (maxima.sourceforge.net) or Sympy (sympy.org). In fact I wouldn't be surprised if someone has already solved this problem.

Comment: @RobertDodier as far as I understood and researched a Bezier curve of nth degree is impossible to find the arc length unless you approximate using sampling or techniques like gauss quadrature and to be honest I have no idea what you mean by finding the arc length symbolically.

Comment: By symbolically I just mean a result that can be expressed in terms of the points and any other parameters. I see that others have worked on the problem and there is no general solution.

Comment: Never, ever, implement the factorial that way. The "I learned about recursion with factorial or golden ratio" functions are cute but incredibly poor implementations: just hardcode a lookup table. Same for binomial coefficients: we _know_ what they are, we've been using them for centuries, they take up no space compared to any of the other code in  your file: don't write functions for them, except to catch the "this result is not in my lookup yet" case. Just because you can mathematically express a recursive relation, does not mean you should _program_ a recursive relation.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks that’s a good idea and that is what I actually end up doing my my most current version of the code (not posted here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve my problem. I found out that I was doing 2 things wrong 1) I was calculating the derivative incorrectly and 2) as per @dmuir response above I was not using the derivative for calculating the Integral.

Here is my code which returns the correct bezier curve arc length:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import org.waltonrobotics.controller.PathData;
import org.waltonrobotics.controller.Pose;

/**
 * Everything about Bezier Curves https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/
 */
public class DynamicBezierCurve extends Path {

    private final double startVelocity;
    private final double endVelocity;
    private final int degree;
    private double[] coefficients;

    /**
     * This constructor is used with the splines, but feel free to use it when creating your own motions
     *
     * @param vCruise - the cruise velocity of the robot
     * @param aMax - the maximum acceleration of the robot
     * @param startVelocity - the start velocity
     * @param endVelocity - the end velocity
     * @param isBackwards - whether or not to move the robot backwards
     * @param controlPoints - the control points that define the curve
     */
    public DynamicBezierCurve(double vCruise, double aMax, double startVelocity, double endVelocity,
        boolean isBackwards, List<Pose> controlPoints) {
        super(vCruise, aMax, isBackwards, controlPoints);
        this.startVelocity = startVelocity;
        this.endVelocity = endVelocity;
        // The starting average encoder distance should always be 0

        degree = getKeyPoints().size() - 1;
        coefficients = calculateCoefficients(degree);
    }

    public DynamicBezierCurve(double vCruise, double aMax, double startVelocity, double endVelocity,
        boolean isBackwards,
        Pose... controlPoints) {
        this(vCruise, aMax, startVelocity, endVelocity, isBackwards, Arrays.asList(controlPoints));
    }

    /**
     * Uses the formula to find the value of nCr
     *
     * @return nCr
     */
    private static double findNumberOfCombination(int n, int r) {
        int nFactorial = factorial(n);
        int rFactorial = factorial(r);
        int nMinusRFactorial = factorial(n - r);

        return nFactorial / (rFactorial * nMinusRFactorial);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the factorial of any integer or double, d
     *
     * @return the factorial of d
     */
    private static int factorial(int d) {
        int result = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i <= d; i++) {
            result = result * i;
        }

        return result;
    }


    public double computeArcLength() {

        int n = 100;

        GaussLegendre gl = new GaussLegendre(n, -1, 1);

        double[] t = gl.getNodes();
        double[] C = gl.getWeights();
        double z = 1;

        double sum = 0;

        double zDivision = z / 2;

        for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
            double ti = t[i];
            ti = zDivision * ti + zDivision;

            Pose point = getDerivative(ti);

            double Ci = C[i];

            sum += Ci * Math.hypot(point.getX(), point.getY());
        }

        sum = zDivision * sum;

        return sum;
    }

    @Override
    public PathData createPathData(double startAverageEncoderLength, PathData previousPathData, double percentage) {
        Pose centerPoint = getPoint(percentage);

        PathData pathData;
//      pathData= calculateData(startAverageEncoderLength, previousPathData, centerPoint);
        pathData = new PathData(centerPoint);
        return pathData;
    }


    private Pose getDerivative(double percentage) {
        double dx = 0;
        double dy = 0;

        if (percentage == 1.0) {

            int last = getKeyPoints().size() - 1;

            dx = getKeyPoints().get(last).getX()
                - getKeyPoints().get(last - 1).getX();
            dy = getKeyPoints().get(last).getY()
                - getKeyPoints().get(last - 1).getY();
        } else {

            double[] coefficients = calculateCoefficients(degree - 1);

            for (int i = 0; i < degree; i++) {

                Pose pointI = getKeyPoints().get(i);

                double multiplier =
                    coefficients[i] * StrictMath.pow(1 - percentage, ((degree - 1) - i)) * StrictMath
                        .pow(percentage, (double) i);

                Pose nextPointI = getKeyPoints().get(i + 1);

                dx += (multiplier = multiplier * (degree)) * (nextPointI.getX() - pointI.getX());
                dy += multiplier * (nextPointI.getY() - pointI.getY());
            }
        }

        double angle = StrictMath.atan2(dy, dx);

        if (isBackwards()) {
            angle += Math.PI;
        }
        angle %= (2 * Math.PI);

        return new Pose(dx, dy, angle);
    }

    private Pose getPoint(double percentage) {
        return getPoint(degree, percentage);
    }

    /**
     * @param percentage - t
     * @return the Pose that is at percentage t along the curve
     */
    private Pose getPoint(double degree, double percentage) {
        double xCoordinateAtPercentage = 0;
        double yCoordinateAtPercentage = 0;

        double dx = 0;
        double dy = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= degree; i++) {

            Pose pointI = getKeyPoints().get(i);

            double multiplier =
                coefficients[i] * StrictMath.pow(1 - percentage, (degree - i)) * StrictMath.pow(percentage, (double) i);

            xCoordinateAtPercentage += (multiplier * pointI.getX());
            yCoordinateAtPercentage += (multiplier * pointI.getY());

            if (percentage != 1 && i < degree) {
                Pose nextPointI = getKeyPoints().get(i + 1);

                dx += (multiplier = multiplier * (degree)) * (nextPointI.getX() - pointI.getX());
                dy += multiplier * (nextPointI.getY() - pointI.getY());
            }
        }

        if (percentage == 1.0) {
            int last = getKeyPoints().size() - 1;

            dx = getKeyPoints().get(last).getX()
                - getKeyPoints().get(last - 1).getX();
            dy = getKeyPoints().get(last).getY()
                - getKeyPoints().get(last - 1).getY();
        }

        double angle = StrictMath.atan2(dy, dx);

        if (isBackwards()) {
            angle += Math.PI;
        }
        angle %= (2 * Math.PI);

        return new Pose(xCoordinateAtPercentage, yCoordinateAtPercentage, angle);
//      return new Pose(dx, dy, angle);
    }


    /**
     * Updates the coefficients used for calculations
     */
    private double[] calculateCoefficients(int degree) {
        double[] coefficients = new double[degree + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < coefficients.length; i++) {
            coefficients[i] = findNumberOfCombination(degree, i);
        }

        return coefficients;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To reduce the cumulative error, you can use

```
sum += Ci * Math.hypot(point.getX(), point.getY());
```

instead of

```
sum += Ci * Math.sqrt(Math.pow(point.getX(), 2) + Math.pow(point.getY(), 2));
```

(however, since the code you posted is incomplete, I cannot use it to verify how much impact this change will have)

Comment: Could also try Neumaier summation

Answer (score 2):

The arc length of a parametrised curve x(p), y(p) between parameter values p1 and p2 is

```
Integral{ p1<=p<=p2 | hypot( xdot(p), ydot(p)) dp
```

where xdot is the derivative of x and ydot of y.

It looks to me as if you are computing

Integral{ p1<=p<=p2 | hypot( x(p), y(p)) dp

instead.